# Pairs of vertices in graph having specific distance

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Given a tree with **N** vertices and a positive number **K**. Find the number of distinct pairs of the vertices which have a distance of *exactly* **K** between them. Note that pairs (v, u) and (u, v) are considered to be the same pair (1 ≤ **N** ≤ 50000, 1 ≤ **K** ≤ 500).

I am not able to find an optimum solution for this. I can do BFS from each vertex and count the no of vertices that is reachable from that and having distance less than or equal to **K**. But then in worst case the complexity will be order of 2. Is there any faster way around??

Comment: Some hints: you tagged this question with dynamic-programming. Can you think of some way that you can reuse previously computed information to compute new distances instead of recomputing them from scratch? Does the fact that trees connect each pair of vertices using exactly one path help?

Comment: Yes i think that dp can be used in this for optimum solution. I have made a table of dp[v][k] (no of vertices in subtree of v having distance exactly k), then i iterated over its childs  for some possible updation in the dp table. But i am not able to find the exact recurrence relation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in more simple way.
Run DFS on tree and for each vertex calculate the distance from the root - save those in array (access by o(1)).

For each pair of vertex in your graph: 
Find their LCA (Lowest common ancestor there are algorithm to do that in 0(1)).
Assume u and v are 2 arbitrary vertices and w is their LCA -> subtract the distance from the w to the root from u to the root - now you have the distance between u and w. Do the same for v -> with o(1) you got the distance for (v,w) and (u,w) -> sum them together and you get the (v,u) distance - now all you have to do is compare to K.

Final complexity is o(n^2)

Comment: Thanks for this good idea. But i already have a O(n^2) algorithm which i described above. I was looking for some more optimum solution, may be using some dynamic programming!

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon the other answer's approach, we can make some key observations.

To calculate distances between two nodes you need their LCA(Lowest Common Ancestor) and depths as the other answer is trying to do. The formula used here is:

> Dist(u, v) = depth[u] + depth[v] - 2 * depth[ lca(u, v) ]

Depth[x] denotes distance of x from root, precomputed using DFS once starting from root node.

Now here comes the key observation, you already have distance value `K`, assume that `dist(u, v) = K` using this assumption calculate(predict?) depth of LCA. By putting K in above formula we get:

> depth[ lca(u, v) ] = (depth[u] + depth[v] - K) / 2

Now that you have depth of LCA you know that distance between `u` and lca is `depth[u] - depth[ lca(u, v) ]` and between `v` and lca is `depth[v] - depth[ lca(u, v) ]`, let this be `X` and `Y` respectively.

Now we know that LCA is the lowest common ancestor thus, the `X`th parent of `u` and `Y`th parent of `v` should be the LCA, so now if `X`th parent of `u` and `Y`th parent of `v` is indeed the same node then we can say that our pre-assumption about distances between the nodes was true and the distance  between the two nodes is `K`.

You can caluculate the Xth and Yth ancestor of the nodes in `O(logN)` complexity using [Binary Lifting Algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/lca_binary_lifting.html)  with a preprocessing of `O(NLogN)` time, this preprocessing can be included directly in your DFS when a node is visited for the first time.

**Corner Cases:**

1. Calcuated depth of LCA should not be a fraction or negative.
2. If depth of any node `u` or `v` matches the calculated depth of the node then that node is the ancestor of the other node.
3. Consider this tree:

[image]

Assuming K = 4, we get that `depth[lca] = 1` using the formula above, and if we get the `Xth` and `Yth` ancestor of `u` and `v` we will get the same node `1`, which should validate our assumption but this is not true since the distance between u and v is actually 2 as visible in the picture above. This is because LCA in this case is actually 2, to handle this case calcuate `X-1`th and `Y-1`th  ancestor of `u` and `v` too, respectively and check if they are different.

**Final Complexity: O(NlogN)**